# Internal observers in a mathematical model

Tags: measurements, observers

In [this abstract](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.4691) the idea of a mathematical model having an internal observer is raised.

A similar suggestion was made to me in a comment just recently.

Is there a name for this methodology of employing an internal observer of the mathematics?

Is it widely used and known?

Comment: I've seen models of the observer as part of the system back to [Everett's "relative state" formulation of quantum mechanics in 1957](http://rmp.aps.org/abstract/RMP/v29/i3/p454_1). Not sure if that is the earliest.

Comment: @dmckee that is fascinating.  He mentions a machine treated as a physical system that has sensory equipment and "even configurations of brain cells" to make measurements with from inside the model. So, is this an isolated case of the internal observer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like dmckee's comment is the most detail this question may get.

In 1957 Hugh Everett published "Relative State" Formulation of Quantum Mechanics in which he proposed a solution to the Measurement Problem. The problem is that it is "[unclear precisely how Everett intended for this to work.](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-everett/)"

Everett's plan is laid out in a section called Observation, and here is a condensed version. He wants to create "a system representing an observer quantum mechanically." He says "the mathematical model seeks to treat the interaction of such an observer with other physical systems" as a physical process. The observer is a machine inside the model "possessing sensory equipment and coupled to recording devices capable of registering past sensory data and machine configurations." "These configurations can be regarded as punches in a paper tape, impressions on a magnetic reel, configurations of a relay switching circuit, or even the configurations of brain cells." Everett proposes a novel technique to derive predictions from the model, by "making deductions about the appearance of phenomena to observers" based on the observer's memory.

What exactly does all that mean?

[This animation and explanation](http://monadpad.com/qm.htm) seems to clarify how you put an internal observer into a model.

Since it doesn't seem to be a very widely known or used technique, the best name for it could be what Everett called it, the "Relative State" formulation.